# Convert PDO sqlite query to array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sqlite, pdo

I'm having a bit of a problem with sqlite on my website and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. I am trying to retrieve content from a row in an sqlite database, which works, but it is stored as a "object" variable. I am trying to convert it to a php "array()". I have tried several ways of doing this but all have failed. This is very frustrating and was wondering if anyone could be kind enough to help. The reason I need this done is so that I can compare 2 arrays to see if there are any matching texts in either of them.

Here is my current code:

```
include("template.php");
// Create (connect to) SQLite database in file
        $file_db = new PDO('sqlite:Scrambled/data.sqlite');
        // Set errormode to exceptions
        $file_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, 
                            PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                            $result = $file_db->query('SELECT * FROM users');
                           //$results = array(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
                           $resultslist = array();
                            while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
                             $resultslist[$row] = $row['users'];
                             }
$qualifiedpeople = explode("\n", file_get_contents('Scrambled/roboticsmembers.txt'));
//$lol = array(fetch_assoc($qualifiedpeople));
$members = array_intersect($qualifiedpeople, $resultslist);
echo("$resultslist");
echo("$qualifiedpeople");
//foreach($members as $member) {
    //echo("$member \n");
//}
```

As you can see I have tried different things and some lines are commented out for later reference.

You can see the error right here: citadelwars.net/members.php

"Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\wamp\www\members.php on line 12"
I have not found this error in all of my googling, but I'm sure it means that the pdo is giving me an "object" variable when it needs to be a resource. Can you tell me if there's any way around fixing this?

Comment: Just explore examples from: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: And it's typically good practice to use the {} code button to encase your code directly into stackoverflow. This way other users with the same issue can easily find the answer.

Comment: @sectus Can't find anything very helpful on the link you sent me but I'll keep looking.

Comment: Can't believe noone else responded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution and what I did wrong;
I was able to replace:

```
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
   $resultslist[$row] = $row['users'];
}
```

With this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($result as $row) {
   $resultslist[$i] = $row['name'];
   $i++;
}
```

Which worked perfectly.

Also for comparing the tables I replaced `explode("\n",` with `explode("\r\n",`